# expo Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.197.216.164:443

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I tried to run React Native android simulator via expo on my android

I've been encountering this error this past 24 hours

```
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.197.216.164:443
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16)
```

and on my android , it said "something went wrong , network response timed out"

I've upgrade expo version both in my PC and Android

idk what else to do
since I can't find any solution for this online

Can anyone help please ?

Comment: Have you been able to connect to this server before? Have you tried to reproduce it on your PC, i.e. "telnet 104.197.216.164 443" and see if the port even opens from your PC to that network. 443 is a common port (https), so I can't imagine why it wouldn't. I'm less familiar with the android simulator, but are there network sandbox settings where it is/isn't allow to reach out to certain hosts on or beyond your network? This IP resolves to google servers, so I'm guessing it needs to access the public Internet to finish whatever it wants to do.

Answer (score 2):

some times the expo server is down,
it can be solve ,
try again later

Answer (score 1):

you have (access denied 403) error . It means it have problem with your region. you need to change your IP to another region with VPN or VPS or Proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Check your internet connection for your device, then run the command `expo start` again.