# expo build:android, Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 34.132.55.135:443

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

I'm trying to run

```
expo build:android
```

but it's showing me this result

```
connect ETIMEDOUT 34.132.55.135:443
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 34.132.55.135:443
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1142:16)
```

I'm not sure what is going on, I've seen another question like this but it was 7 months ago here [expo Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.197.216.164:443](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66687374/expo-error-connect-etimedout-104-197-216-164443)
, I can't find any solutions. Please Help.

this is my app.json file

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "appName",
    "slug": "appName",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
},
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.company.appName",
      "buildNumber": "1.0.0"
    },
    "android": {
      "versionCode": 1,
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      },
      "package": "appName.company.com"
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by resetting my internet router.

I realized that it was a network error because there were some domain servers that my network could not reach.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).